# How to setup ssl using only .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https, httpd.conf

Has anyone tried to setup ssl for a website using only .htaccess file?

I read through many documents which points to apache's httpd.conf file, to add some lines inside `<virtual-host>` tag.
But I don't have access to httpd.conf file on my web hosting ...
I can only put . htaccess file in my hosting directory.
So is there a way to achieve HTTPS website using only the .htaccess file.

NOTE: I already have certificates for my domain.

Comment: If you already have the SSL certs installed, then what do you need .htaccess for?

Comment: Your hosting provider most likely has some way to upload certificates, and there will also be some way to activate SSL, if it is not enabled automatically by uploading the certificate.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Yes my Hosting provider gives a way to add SSL , but they charge huge amount for this , but i got the certificates from LetsEncrypt for free and wanted to use them for my website

Comment: Some hosts allow you to upload your own SSL certs for use. GoDaddy, for one, lets you do it. I'm not sure about the other hosts.

Comment: @Raaghu ᴄɢɪ script ?

Answer (score 4):

You can redirect from plain HTTP to HTTPS, but you cannot activate SSL/TLS from htaccess.

To activate SSL/TLS, you must use [`SSLEngine`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslengine) among other directives

```
SSLEngine on
```

As you can see from the documentation,

> Context:   server config, virtual host

this is only possible in server config or virtual host context, but not in directory and .htaccess context.

This means, you must go through the means your web hosting provider gives you. Probably, activating alone is less expensive or even free of charge, when you already have certificates. Usually, certificates are the expensive part in using HTTPS. Activating SSL in contrast is a one time configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't. If you only can modify htaccess files, maybe your hosting provider give you another way to set up your certificates. If not, you can't do it.

Comment: What about ᴄɢɪ script for ʜᴛᴛᴘꜱ over port 80 ?

Answer (score 0):

(1) You will need a verified certificate from your hosting company or another company.

```
(1.1) https://www.ionos.co.uk/security/ssl-certificate?ar=1#packages
(1.2) https://letsencrypt.org/
```

(2) Once it is setup and you can connect to your site with https://yourdoman.com you need to edit your .htaccess file in the document root. Just because you have a certificate of authentication does not make you secure. Firstly you need to enforce HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS). I quote "HSTS allows a site to request that it always be contacted over HTTPS. HSTS is supported in Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Edge and IE" (chromium.org/hsts, 2020). Also you need to redirect none port 443 (https://) traffic such as port 80 (http://) to port 443. This combination should assure encrypted communications. But that still doesn't make you secure, because you could have an insecure SSL/TLS versions still available on the server you're renting. I hope this helps a little.

The following is copied and pasted out of my .htaccess file;

```
##############################################
# HTTP STRICT TRANSPORT SECURITY             #
##############################################

# Use HTTP Strict Transport Security to force client to use secure connections only
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS

##############################################
# ENABLE REWRITE ENGINE                      #
##############################################

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

##############################################
# FORCE PORT 443                             #
##############################################

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

#Force 443 no 80
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdoman.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I hope this helps someone, regards...

Answer (score -1):

To force SSL all you need to use is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Obviously, you need to own the SSL certificates, you mentioned in your question that you ***do*** own these.

Comment: this forces only redirect to https, not ssl itself